# Best way to synchronize a data model object among multiple "editor" forms

Tags: java, vaadin14

I have a Java Vaadin (Flow) application that allows a user to edit a task. This portion of the application consists of a main form and some sub-forms:

```
EditTaskForm.java
    EditTaskDetailsForm.java
    EditNotesForm.java
        EditNoteForm.java
```

All of this allows editing for one "task" at a time. The task has a number of attributes, including a list of "notes". The top-level form allows for editing the title and description and the means to access the lower-level editors. The details form allows for editing various simple attributes. The notes form allows for the management (adding, deleting, editing) of a collection of notes associated with the task. The lowest level form allows for the editing of a single note associated with a task.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to design this collection of related forms to populate all forms with the pertinent data from the specified task, and the best way to save any changes made in any of these forms to that task and its related objects.

At this time, I've been passing the task object to the main form, which then passes it to the sub forms. This has been working reasonably well for populating the forms, but saving information is proving to be difficult. I'm not sure if each form should be responsible for saving changes, or if it should be handled in the main form, or somewhere else.

Are there any "best practices" on how this should be done?

Comment: Have you checked Vaadin documentation for Binder?